# send more parameters in swagger Available authorizations pop up

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I am developing web API in ASP.NET Core.

I am looking for a way for sending parameter beside authorization in swagger to send them in header

Answer (score 0):

Add AddSecurityDefinition in options. https://gist.github.com/mbasaran/39734d645edcc258fcb507a710139b7d

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "api", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new ApiKeyScheme
    {
        Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
        In = "header",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = "apiKey"
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry
I said more parameters.
I want to send parameters other than authentication

Answer (score -1):

[image]

add parameters inside Available authorizations under Authorization input

Comment: As it currently is, this answer makes no sense.

Comment: If you looked good. This was not the answer to the question, but the completion of the question

Comment: Could you not have updated the question to simply include this? Looking good isn't necessary, this makes no sense as an answer and others viewing this question will not understand what this is trying to portray.